# What is different between execute C program in terminal and execute C program in Java used Runtime.getRuntime().exe()

Tags: java, c, exec, processbuilder

i want to execute C Program used java's method runtime.getRuntime().exec();

but if i execute C program used getRuntime(), sometime C program is die....

but if i execute C program in terminal, never die C program...

There are two different ways at some point go?

ps. processBuilder Method also alike

Comment: You'd need a whole lot more explanation in order for anyone to help you with this. What C program? What Java code are you using to execute it? What error do you get with the C program dies?

Answer (score 2):

When you execute a C program from the shell, it inherits all kind of environment variables,and the working directory,  which have been set by the shell.

When you run the program using getRuntime().exec() you don't invoke the shell, but just the program. If your program need specific environment variables set, or has to run in specific directory, you have to provide them in the call.

Comment: Doesn't it inherit JVM process's variables?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I thought it did not, but I just checked,and you are right. If no values are provided, it inherits the environment of the current process.

Comment: Even still, the environment of the program, especially if launched from an IDE (ie: Eclipse) will likely differ greatly from the standard console setup, especially for people like me with massive `.bashrc` files.